# Usage of "since" here

Tags: tenses

At the time of this writing, Chinese stocks are up since the bear market bottom in 2005.

How come it's not "stocks have been up"? I thought we should stick with the perfect tense with the word "since".

Comment: You might say that the perfect is redundant because the past/anterior meaning is conveyed by "since".

Comment: I'm not too happy with it. I'd switch to 'At the time of writing, Chinese stocks are up from the bear market low in 2005.'

Answer (score 1):

This is one feature of *journalese* (a style of writing used mostly in newspapers). Reports and especially headlines are reported in present tense even though they happened in the past.

**Example**

Suppose a dog has been bitten by a man. In normal language, we might report this as, **A dog has been bitten by a man!**

As a newspaper headline, it would be **Man bites dog!**

[image]

Comment: @ Yosef Baskin - Corrected